# Mod Rewrite that will accept both with slash and without slash

Tags: mod-rewrite

I currently have this in my htaccess file

```
RewriteRule ^(cms/.*)$ cms.php?querystring=$1 [L,QSA]
```

This is to get everything after the domain name

Currently, if I enter `www.mydomain/classified/` there is no problem

but if I enter `www.mydomain/classified` (without slash at the end) it will fire the 404 page

I need a modification to the rewrite rule [`^(cms/.*)$`] wherein it will not fire a 404 page if I enter
`www.mydomain/classified` (without slash at the end)

but will show 404 if I enter

```
www.mydomain/classified-any-text-here/
```

or

```
www.mydomain/classified-any-text-here
```

Answer (score 0):

You can test following codes

```
 [^(cms/?.*)$]
```